# $| \inf A - \inf B | \le \sup |A - B|$?

Tags: real-analysis

How can we show that

$$\left| \inf_S f(x) - \inf_S g(x)\right| \le \sup_S \left| f(x) - g(x)\right|\,?$$

I started with $\left| \sup_S f -g\right|\le \sup_S \left| f- g\right|$. And $\left| \sup_S f-g\right| = \left| \sup_S f -\inf_S g\right|$. But why is it true that

$$\left| \inf f - \inf g\right| \le \left|\sup f - \inf g\right|\,?$$

Comment: I'm confused by the notation $|\sup_Sf-g|$  Does this mean the same thing as $|\sup_S(f-g)|?$  If so, how is that equal to $|\sup_S f-\inf_S g|$.

Comment: @saulspatz yes it's $(f-g)$. I made a typo and will correct it now.

Comment: @saulspatz I was thinking of something like $\sup (A-B) = \sup(A) + \sup(-B) = \sup(A) - \inf(B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an $\epsilon>0$, find some $x\in S$ such that $\inf g+\epsilon>g(x)$, then 
\begin{align*}
\inf f-\inf g-\epsilon&<\inf f-g(x)\\
&\leq f(x)-g(x)\\
&\leq|f(x)-g(x)|\\
&\leq\sup|f-g|,
\end{align*}
since this is true for all $\epsilon>0$, then $\inf f-\inf g\leq\sup|f-g|$. Swiping the roles of $f$ and $g$, one has $\inf g-\inf f\leq\sup|g-f|=\sup|f-g|$, so we conclude that $|\inf f-\inf g|\leq\sup|f-g|$.